# Handle Exception from a third-party library where Exception is not predefined

Tags: python, python-3.x, request

There is a **json()** method in the **requests** library.

I want to handle his exceptions, "if suddenly something is wrong." For example, the server did not respond with json, but with something else, well, there are all kinds of problems with encodings, etc.

I climbed into the documentation, then into the sources, and realized that in the end, in the **requests** itself, everything is tied to two libraries at once:

```
try:
    import simplejson as json
except ImportError:
    import json
```

Accordingly, there are two types of exceptions for each of them at once.

And I have a "combined arms" library, which I would like to use in independent conditions from the installed system, libraries, etc.

How to correctly register in this case

```
try:
   answer = requests.get (url, param, headers) .json ()
except (???, ???, ???):
   do_my_function (incorrect_answer)
```

so that it does not depend on the libraries the import took place, and with them their specific exceptions?

Comment: Both versions of `JSONDecodeError` subclass `ValueError` (which makes sense, as they've been given a string whose value isn't valid JSON): https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/blob/master/simplejson/errors.py#L26, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/960fca1a5887a277fd6031cf4c4b6fb31b08ebf5/Lib/json/decoder.py#L20

Comment: @jonrsharpe And this exception will block all heirs?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. If you're asking whether `except ValueError:` would work in either case, then: yes, but it will also catch any *other* `ValueError`s (e.g. from `requests` itself).

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok. thank you. i try it.

Comment: But actually I would like to handle not so widely ... :)
After all, in the same way it is considered very bad form to write something like except  Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you climbed into the source, you should go to the end. And also the documentation can help.

In the [documentation] [1] on requests json () it says:

> In case the JSON decoding fails, `r.json ()` raises an exception. For example, if the response gets a 204 (No Content), or if the response contains invalid JSON, attempting `r.json ()` raises `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.

We must catch the `ValueError` exception:

```
try:
  answer = requests.get (url, param, headers).json ()
except ValueError:
  do_my_function (incorrect_answer)
```

If you look at the json and simplejson sources, you can see that both packages use a more accurate exception inherited from `ValueError`:`JSONDecodeError`. Thus, you can do this:

```
try:
  from simplejson import JSONDecodeError
except ImportError:
  from json import JSONDecodeError
```

...

```
try:
  answer = requests.get (url, param, headers) .json ()
except JSONDecodeError:
  do_my_function (incorrect_answer)
```

[1]: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content